# R Cannot coerce class "function" to a data.frame - Using logit results from matchit with PseudoR2

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem with PseudoR2, which throws the following error after using the logit object from matchit:

*Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame*

It seems to work with a normal logit, but even though the logit from matchit seems identical in every way, it gives an error.

See a reproducible example below:

```
## Load libraries
library(MatchIt)
library(DescTools)

## Load data
data(mtcars)

## Use matchit to match data
matched <- matchit(vs ~ mpg + cyl,
                   method = "nearest", data = mtcars)

m1 <- matched$model ## Retrieve logit data from matchit
m2 <- glm(vs ~ mpg + cyl, family = binomial(logit), data = mtcars) ## Own logit

PseudoR2(m1)
PseudoR2(m2)
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works just fine! Maybe you have overwritten some variables earlier? Try restarting R...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The code above works for me. `cannot coerce class ‘"function"’` usually means that you tried to call an object which does not exist but happens to be the name of a function: e.g., `as.data.frame(glm)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Restarting R did not work. Since both of you could not reproduce, I decided to update R from 3.6.1 to 3.6.3. This seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating R (from 3.6.1) to 3.6.3 seemed to solve the problem.